# Don't work pagination on new Instagram url-api for locations (?__a=1) (native_location_data)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram began to give a new response to the request https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/.../?__a=1 :
{"graphql":{"native_location_data:{...

*old response is: {"graphql":{"location":{...*

Pagination https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/.../?__a=1&max_id=... don't work: Instagram responds as well as the first request (https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/.../?__a=1)

P.S. Pagination for tags (with a new response) works correctly

P.P.S. Not all users have a new response to the request

Answer (score 0):

The "native_location_data" response Object requires a different function to traverse. For example, if you want to catch all images, use this example:

```
                sections = instagram_resp['native_location_data']['recent']['sections']
                for sub_section in sections:
                    if sub_section['layout_type'] == 'media_grid':
                        for item in sub_section['layout_content']['medias']:
                            if item['media'].get('image_versions2'):
                                largest_res = sorted(
                                    item['media']['image_versions2']['candidates'],
                                    key=lambda o: o['height'] * o['width']
                                )[-1]['url']
```